# Access existing Azure Web Sites via Azure Cloud Service RDP

Tags: iis, azure, azure-web-app-service

Given:

- Couple of websites created using Azure Web Sites execution model.
- No RDP access since Azure Web Sites doesn't provide it.
- Possibility to install/create Cloud Service on Azure. Cloud Service
  does have RDP access to its websites.

Question:

Will it be possible to access the existing websites via RDP on Cloud Service?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you had deployed your sites in Azure Cloud Services and enabled RD, you can very well look at the setup and config of your site(s) under it.

However if you make any changes, it may not be reflected to the setup as the Azure Cloud Services is non persistent and during any Data center activities like load balancing the fabric controller may just pull of your instance and re-deploy in someother instance. During this process all your changes will be lost and the original package of cscsf and cscfg will utilized during deployment.

Comment: So is it possible to RDP old sites (created within Azure Web Sites mode)?

Comment: Azure Web Sites don't support RD. Azure Virtual Machines and Azure Cloud Services do support RD.